# React JS Bootstrap Dropdown Issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a filter in my React.js project. However, I am having an issue where the list shows when you click on the button, but the list will not go away on the second click or if you click outside the list.

I imported the bootstrap CSS, and while that resolved the button issue, it messed with my styling, so I commented out the import. Is anyone able to help me resolve either issue?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// import '../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css';
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
import Popper from 'popper.js';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import DropdownButton from 'react-bootstrap/DropdownButton';
import './Filterbar.css';

export default function Filterbar() {
    function handlePropertyTypeChange(event){
        console.log(event.target.value);
        event = setPropteryType(event.target.value);
    };
    function handlePriceRangeChange(event){
        console.log(event.target.value);
        event = setPriceRange(event.target.value);
    };
    function handleBedroomChange(event){
        console.log(event.target.value);
        event = setBedroomQTY(event.target.value);
    };
    function handleBathroomChange(event){
        console.log(event.target.value);
        event = setBathroomQTY(event.target.value);
    };
    function handleCityChange(event){
        console.log(event.target.value);
        event = setCityChoice(event.target.value);
    };

    const [propertyType, setPropteryType] = useState('');
    const [priceRange, setPriceRange] = useState('');
    const [BedroomQTY, setBedroomQTY] = useState('');
    const [BathroomQTY, setBathroomQTY] = useState('');
    const [cityChoice, setCityChoice] = useState('');

    return (
        <div className='FilterbarBody'>

            <DropdownButton type="button" id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Property Type &#8964;" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <Dropdown.Item value={0} name="Property Type" onChange={handlePropertyTypeChange} aria-labelledby="dropdown-basic-button">All</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={1} name="Property Type" onChange={handlePropertyTypeChange} aria-labelledby="dropdown-basic-button">Single Family Home</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={2} name="Property Type" onChange={handlePropertyTypeChange} aria-labelledby="dropdown-basic-button">Multi Family Home</Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>

            <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button2" title="Price &#8964;">
                <Dropdown.Item value={0} name="Price Range" onChange={handlePriceRangeChange}>All</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={500} name="Price Range" onChange={handlePriceRangeChange}>500+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={1000} name="Price Range" onChange={handlePriceRangeChange}>1,000+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={1500} name="Price Range" onChange={handlePriceRangeChange}>1,500+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={2000} name="Price Range" onChange={handlePriceRangeChange}>2,000+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={2500} name="Price Range" onChange={handlePriceRangeChange}>2,500+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={3000} name="Price Range" onChange={handlePriceRangeChange}>3,000+</Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>

            <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button3" title="Bedroom &#8964;">
                <Dropdown.Item value={0} name="Bedroom" onChange={handleBedroomChange}>All</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={1} name="Bedroom" onChange={handleBedroomChange}>1+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={2} name="Bedroom" onChange={handleBedroomChange}>2+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={3} name="Bedroom" onChange={handleBedroomChange}>3+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={4} name="Bedroom" onChange={handleBedroomChange}>4+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={5} name="Bedroom" onChange={handleBedroomChange}>5+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={6} name="Bedroom" onChange={handleBedroomChange}>6+</Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>

            <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button4" title="Bathroom &#8964;">
                <Dropdown.Item value={0} name="Bathroom" onChange={handleBathroomChange}>All</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={1} name="Bathroom" onChange={handleBathroomChange}>1+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={2} name="Bathroom" onChange={handleBathroomChange}>2+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={3} name="Bathroom" onChange={handleBathroomChange}>3+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={4} name="Bathroom" onChange={handleBathroomChange}>4+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={5} name="Bathroom" onChange={handleBathroomChange}>5+</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={6} name="Bathroom" onChange={handleBathroomChange}>6+</Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>

            <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button5" title="City &#8964;">
                <Dropdown.Item value={""} name="City" onChange={handleCityChange}>All</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={"Cape Coral"} name="City" onChange={handleCityChange}>Cape Coral</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={"Fort Myers"} name="City" onChange={handleCityChange}>Fort Myers</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item value={"Lehigh Acres"} name="City" onChange={handleCityChange}>Lehigh Acres</Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```css
.FilterbarBody {
    display: block;
    background-color:gainsboro;
    width: 53em;
    height: 2.50em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1.50em;
    border: .13em solid #808080;
    font-style: 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
.FilterbarBody > .dropdown {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: 'sans-serif';
}
.FilterbarBody > .dropdown > button {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 1.23em;
    margin-right: 1.23em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(250, 235, 215, 0);
    padding: .75em 1.75em;
    font-size: 1em;
    list-style: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .50em;
}
.FilterbarBody > .dropdown > button:hover {
    background-color:rgba(250, 240, 230, 0);
    color: red;
}
.dropdown-item {
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 0.010em solid linen;
    font-style: 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: .25em;
    padding: 1em 1.75em;
}
.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: linen;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Well, the CSS file from Bootstrap is the one that help the component toggle, so you need that file. 
Also, there's no point on using Bootstrap if you're going to customize the styles manually, but if you still want to go that way, check how you should be doing it [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/#custom-dropdown-components)

Comment: Also, you are not using inputs, so you should be using `onClick` instead of `onChange`. And the line `event = setPriceRange(event.target.value);` is wrong, you're overwriting the event with a state change; it makes no sense. Just keep it as `setPriceRange(event.target.value);` that way you trigger the render and have the value updated

Comment: @Thremulant But how come the bootstrap CSS overwrites all my CSS files?

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't overwrite files. It may _override_ CSS style rules, but that's something you have to deal with when using any style library. The best approach is to load Bootstrap's CSS first, then create your customizations. Doing the reverse is a recipe for frustration.

Comment: Please tag React and your Bootstrap version.

Comment: @Thremulant, a lead frontend developer should know to [never link "here"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/). Accessibility is crucial in your line of work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [React Select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select), which appears to be working much more in my favor now. I have a demo below, and
I will provide more updates here if I run into any issues.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Select from 'react-select';
import './Filterbar.css'

const propertyTypeOptions = [
  { value: 'All', label: 'All' },
  { value: 'Single Family Home', label: 'Single Family Home' },
  { value: 'Multi Family Home', label: 'Multi Family Home' },
];
const propertyPriceOptions = [
  { value: 0, label: 'All' },
  { value: 500, label: '500' },
  { value: 1000, label: '1,000' },
  { value: 1500, label: '1,500' },
  { value: 2000, label: '2,000' },
  { value: 2500, label: '2,500' },
  { value: 3000, label: '3,000' },
  { value: 3500, label: '3,500' },
];
const propertyBedroomOptions = [
  { value: 0, label: 'All' },
  { value: 1, label: '1' },
  { value: 2, label: '2' },
  { value: 3, label: '3' },
  { value: 4, label: '4' },
  { value: 5, label: '5' },
  { value: 6, label: '6' },
  { value: 7, label: '7' },
  { value: 8, label: '8' },
  { value: 9, label: '9' },
];
const propertyBathroomOptions = [
  { value: 0, label: 'All' },
  { value: 1, label: '1' },
  { value: 2, label: '2' },
  { value: 3, label: '3' },
  { value: 4, label: '4' },
  { value: 5, label: '5' },
  { value: 6, label: '6' },
  { value: 7, label: '7' },
  { value: 8, label: '8' },
  { value: 9, label: '9' },
];
const propertyCityOptions = [
  { value: 'All', label: 'All' },
  { value: 'Cape Coral', label: 'Cape Coral' },
  { value: 'Fort Myers', label: 'Fort Myers' },
  { value: 'Lehigh Acres', label: 'Lehigh Acres' },
];
class RentalFilterbar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedPropertyTypeOptions: null,
    selectedPriceOptions: null,
  };
  handleChangePropertyTypeOptions = (selectedPropertyTypeOptions) => {
    this.setState({ selectedPropertyTypeOptions }, () =>
      console.log(`propertyTypeOptions selected:`, this.state.selectedPropertyTypeOptions)
      );
  };
  handleChangePropertyPriceOptions = (selectedPropertyPriceOptions) => {
    this.setState({ selectedPropertyPriceOptions }, () =>
      console.log(`selectedPropertyPriceOptions selected:`, this.state.selectedPropertyPriceOptions)
      );
  };
  handleChangePropertyBedroomOptions = (selectedPropertyBedroomOptions) => {
    this.setState({ selectedPropertyBedroomOptions }, () =>
      console.log(`selectedPropertyBedroomOptions selected:`, this.state.selectedPropertyBedroomOptions)
      );
  };
  handleChangePropertyBathroomOptions = (selectedPropertyBathroomOptions) => {
    this.setState({ selectedPropertyBathroomOptions }, () =>
      console.log(`selectedPropertyBathroomOptions selected:`, this.state.selectedPropertyBathroomOptions)
      );
  };
  handleChangePropertyCityOptions = (selectedPropertyCityOptions) => {
    this.setState({ selectedPropertyCityOptions }, () =>
      console.log(`selectedPropertyCityOptions selected:`, this.state.selectedPropertyCityOptions)
      );
  };
  render() {
    const { selectedPropertyTypeOptions, selectedPropertyPriceOptions, selectedPropertyBedroomOptions, selectedPropertyBathroomOptions, selectedPropertyCityOptions } = this.state;
    return (
        <>
        <form onChange={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>Property Type:
                <Select
                    value={selectedPropertyTypeOptions}
                    onChange={this.handleChangePropertyTypeOptions}
                    options={propertyTypeOptions}
                />
            </label>
            <label>Max Price:
                <Select
                    value={selectedPropertyPriceOptions}
                    onChange={this.handleChangePropertyPriceOptions}
                    options={propertyPriceOptions}
                />
            </label>
            <label>Min Bed:
                <Select
                    value={selectedPropertyBedroomOptions}
                    onChange={this.handleChangePropertyBedroomOptions}
                    options={propertyBedroomOptions}
                />
            </label>
            <label>Min Bath:
                <Select
                    value={selectedPropertyBathroomOptions}
                    onChange={this.handleChangePropertyBathroomOptions}
                    options={propertyBathroomOptions}
                />
            </label>
            <label>City:
                <Select
                    value={selectedPropertyCityOptions}
                    onChange={this.handleChangePropertyCityOptions}
                    options={propertyCityOptions}
                />
            </label>
        </form>
        </>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <RentalFilterbar />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
form {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70em;
}
form > label {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 1.15em;
}
form > label > .css-b62m3t-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.25em;
    margin-right: 0.75em;
    width: 7.1255em;
    font-family: 'sans-serif';
    size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: If your answer doesn't address the actual question, please either revise the question appropriately or delete it. An abandoned question doesn't benefit the community.